# Space between two rows in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, row

How to add space between two bootstrap table rows?

I need somehow like:

```
---------
| A   B |
---------
---------
| C   D |
---------
---------
| E   F |
---------
```

See Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-dark">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> The styles `border-collapse: separate;` and `border-spacing:0 20px;`
>   will work when I add the class `table-bordered` in the table, by that
>   I will get a line between two columns which I don't need!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `border-collapse` and `border-spacing`...

```
.table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing:0 20px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/76fzFtggt2

Comment: As your code will work if I add the class `table-bordered` in it. But then I will also get a line between two columns which I don't need!